# Не работает вызов функции через Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

Хочу написать небольшую апишку на flask, которая при переходе на /get_domain_users будет вызывать асинхронную функцию при помощи Celery, чтобы получить данные из бд и закинуть в json, который впоследствии вывести на экран. При этом почему-то при срабатывании `file.get()` программа останавливается и, соответсвенно, никого вывода json на экран не происходит. Что еще интересно, при дебаге, программа не заходит в `file = parse_users.delay()`. Очень нужны советы, идей нет. Код прилагаю ниже

```
from flask import Flask
import pika, conf, sys, json
from celery import Celery
from databaseworker.database import engine, Neo4jUsers
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task()
def parse_users():
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    with Session(bind=engine) as session:
        data = session.query(Neo4jUsers).all()

        json_file = []
        for i in data:
            json_file.append(
                {
                    "name" : i.name, 
                    "objectid" : i.objectid
                }
            )
        
        file = json.dumps(json_file)
    return file

@app.route('/get_domain_users')
def get_domain_users():
    file = None
    with open("test.json") as js:
        data = json.load(js)

        if data["query"] == "users":
           file = parse_users.delay()
    
    return file.get()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Фразы «при срабатывании file.get() программа останавливается» и «программа не заходит в file = parse_users.delay()» противоречат друг другу, в показанном вами коде эти два события не могут случиться одновременно